# Meteor - How to register helpers with dynamic names?

Tags: meteor, helper

Can I register helpers with dynamic names?

For instance:

```
for (var a=0; a<3; a++){
  var arr = ['a','b','c']
  Template.registerHelper(arr[a], function(){
    return arr[a];
  })
}
```

with this html:

```
<p>{{a}}{{b}}{{c}}</p>
```

would render

`abc`

Answer (score 0):

You question is kinda unclear of what you're really trying to accomplish, but something like that should work:

```
var templates = {
    'a': function () {return "Something"},
    'b': function () {return "Something"},
    'c': function () {return "Something"}
};

Object.keys(templates).forEach(function(helperName){
    Template.registerHelper(helperName, function(){
        return templates[helperName];
    })
});
```

Comment: That's basically what I tried but in object form instead of an array.  That didn't work for me.  Thanks anyways.

Comment: I'm simply trying to create/register new helpers from user input.

Comment: Wouldnt be simpler to use ReactiveDict ?

Comment: Possibly.  Would I have to predefine all the helpers?  This is my issue.  I'm looking to get the helper names from text input.  Say someone wrote `blah` in an input field.  Could I then grab the `$('div').text()` and create a {{blah}} helper out of it?